# cuda and cudnn not working after successful installation

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I am using anaconda python 3.6 on ubuntu 16.04. I have systme with quadro 4000 graphics card. I have installed `cuda 9.0.176` and `cudnn 7.1.4` for running tensorflow and keras. while running code i am getting following error:

```
2019-07-09 14:20:49.199895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Quadro K4000 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8105
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 2.94GiB freeMemory: 2.46GiB
2019-07-09 14:20:49.199946: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1482] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Quadro K4000, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2019-07-09 14:20:49.199969: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-07-09 14:20:49.199983: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-07-09 14:20:49.199995: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
```

this appears and simulation stops. how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu you need a GPU that supports at least Cuda compute capability 3.5. The K4000 is not supported

> For a GPU with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0, or different versions of the NVIDIA libraries, see the [Linux build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) guide

Comment: So, should i have to remove cuda and cudnn

Comment: Only Tensorflow needs to be built from source with the support for CUDA Compute Capability 3.0. A link from Google with a guide: https://medium.com/@mccann.matt/compiling-tensorflow-with-cuda-3-0-support-42d8fe0bf3b5